# How do I fill the space between multiple line segments in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, charts

Suppose I have the following plot in ggplot2:

```
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=15,y=50),shape=19,fill="gray0", size=5)+
  geom_point(aes(x=28, y=75),shape=19, fill="gray0", size=5)+
  geom_point(aes(x=13, y=100),shape=19, fill="gray0", size=5)+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 15, y = 50, xend = 28, yend = 75), size=1)+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 13, y = 100, xend = 28, yend = 75), size=1)+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 15, y = 50, xend = 13, yend = 100), size=1)
```

This plots three line segments intersecting at common points so that a triangle is created. How would I then fill the formed triangle with a color? (Suppose I need to use geom_segment)

Comment: I'd recommend first taking a step back and going through some ggplot tutorials. The online docs provide links to several. `ggplot` generally works on data frames, not just manually input individual numbers, and it works with data in a long format so that you aren't calling the same geom multiple times to do the same thing. Right now there's no information coming in that would say that one segment has anything to do with another, or that there's any meaning to the space inside of them

Answer (score 2):

You can use geom_polygon instead:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(15, 28, 13), y = c(50,75,100))

ggplot() +
      geom_point(df, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y), size = 5) +
      geom_polygon(df, mapping=aes(x = x, y = y), fill="grey")
```

you may want the points on top of the triangle and if so do geom_polygon then geom_point

Comment: Suppose I needed to use a series of geom_segments for the shape construction. Is there a way then to fill in the space between geom_segments?